# How to resolve Prometheus Error 'role missing (one of: pod, service, endpoints, node)'

Tags: configuration, kubernetes, yaml, prometheus

I am trying to apply kubernetes to my minikube cluster for the first time. I have limited experience with cluster management and have never worked with prometheus before so I apologize for noob errors.

I run the following commands:

```
docker build -t my-prometheus .
docker run -p 9090:9090 my-prometheus
```

here is my yaml:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'codelab-monitor'
scrape_configs:
- job_name: 'kubernetes-apiservers'
  scheme: http
  tls_config:
    ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: endpoints
  - api_server: localhost:30000
```

I ran this through YAMLlint and got that it was valid. However I get the following error when I run the second docker command:

```
level=error ts=2018-09-18T21:49:34.365671918Z caller=main.go:617 err="error 
loading config from \"/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml\": couldn't load 
configuration (--config.file=\"/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml\"): parsing 
YAML file /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml: role missing (one of: pod, 
service, endpoints, node)"
```

However, you can see that I have specified my `- role: endpoints` in my `kubernetes_sd_configs`.

Can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`kubernetes_sd_configs` is a list of configs, styled as block sequence in YAML terms.

Now, your list of configs looks like this:

```
- role: endpoints
- api_server: localhost:3000
```

So you're defining two configs, and only the first one of them has a role. This is why you get the error. Most probably, you want to create only one config with `role` and `api_server` configured. Drop the second `-` so that the `api_server` belongs to the first config:

```
- role: endpoints
  api_server: localhost:3000
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you for the quick response and explanation